# how to swipe horizontally and vertically on a widget list

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of widgets I want the first two swipe horizontally and the others vertically displaying all the widgets on the screen
I tried that but it doesn't work .
each widget is wrap in this widget widcard .so what are the changes to be made
here is the structure of all the widgets.it contains the following elements it is the scroll that does not work
I tried with pageview but it doesn't work
how to make it work properly

````
body: SingleChildScrollView(
  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(
                      
                      child: ListView(
                       scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal

                      children: [
                        Widget1(),
                        Widget2()
                      ]),
                    ),
                    Widget3(),

                   
                    Widget4(),

                   
                    widget5(),
                    widget6(),

                   
                  ],
                ),
              ),```












```ListView(
                  children: [
                    SingleChildScrollView(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      child: Row(children: [
                        widget1()
                        widget2()
                      ]),
                    ),
                   
                    widget3()

                    
                    widget4()

                   
                    widget5()

                   
                    widget6()
                  ],
                ));```
````

Comment: What's wrong? you're getting any error?

Comment: the widget is not display and i got  The relevant error-causing widget was ......

Comment: Wrap with Expanded or Flexible Widget.

Comment: not working only errors

Comment: Should the two top widgets scroll up when you scroll up the bottom widgets? Or should the top widgets stay as they are while scrolling up the bottom widgets?

Comment: yes @ TripleNine The two top widgets should also scroll up when I scroll the bottom widgets

Comment: only widget1 must scroll with the others from top to bottom. if I swipe widget 1 it must display widget2

Answer (score 0):

You should use `SingleChildScrollView` for the horizontal scroll and the ListView for vertical scroll. The SingleChildScrollView is the first child of the ListView and also scrolls up if you scroll the bottom widgets.
Just replace `List.generate...` with your list of widgets:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Material App',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Material App Bar'),
        ),
        body: ListView(
          children: [
            SingleChildScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              child: Row(
                children: List.generate(2, (index) => Container(
                  child: Text("$index"),
                  width: 400,
                  height: 200,
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                )),
              ),
            ),
            ...List.generate(5, (index) => Container(
              child: Text("$index"),
              width: 200,
              height: 200,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              color: Colors.red,
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            ))
          ],
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Scrool horizontal not working getting 
The relevant error-causing widget was
Card

Comment: My code works for me on both desktop and mobile. Maybe you should edit your code to show how you placed your Cards in the SingleChildScrollWidget

Comment: I eddit the code each widget is wrap in this widget widcard

Comment: Even with your widcard it's working for me. You should provide the code which wraps the child in widcard. Otherwise I can't help you.

Comment: I edited the code here is the content of the widget

Comment: No error here. Maybe you modified my code incorrectly. Please provide the code with SingleChildScrollView and ListView and also post the full error message.

Comment: I edited the question here is how I used the listeview you suggested

Comment: The code is correct, it seems like I need the whole error message.

Comment: the error=Exception caught by rendering library  RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPhysicalShape#bdd53 relayoutBoundary=up20
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
package:flutter/…/rendering/box.dart:1
Failed assertion: line 1982 pos 12: 'hasSize'

The relevant error-causing widget was
Card

Comment: The error means that you are using a widget inside Card which takes infinite height or width. This problem is not related to this question. You should open a new question and provide full unmodified code.

Comment: no but I only have this error when I want to add the scroll  horizontal otherwise the app works correctly without problem in the terminal

Comment: Put the Card inside a SizedBox and check what happens

Comment: when I put the first two widgets in a cointainer with a width and height the scroll works. but I want the size to be dynamic. that is to say take the available content thank you

Comment: You always have to provide a size. SingleChildScrollView says: "Take as much space as you want". The child however says: "Let me take as much space as I can". You see that both can not be satisfied at the same time. That's why you get the error. Please accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: ok okay I must provide a size?. if so will the widget be displayed correctly on other devices of different sizes. thank you

Comment: It heavily depends on the layout. If you have problems sizing your widgets consider using MediaQuery for a responsive layout.

Answer (score 0):

Using it in the below fashion I'm able to scroll the first row horizontally and the entire Column vertically.

```
SizedBox(
    height: 200,
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 50,
            width: 100,
            child: ListView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              children: const [
                SizedBox(
                  width: 50,
                  child:
                      Card(margin: EdgeInsets.all(5), color: Colors.blue),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 50,
                  child:
                      Card(margin: EdgeInsets.all(5), color: Colors.blue),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 50,
                  child:
                      Card(margin: EdgeInsets.all(5), color: Colors.blue),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
              height: 50,
              width: 50,
              child: Card(margin: EdgeInsets.all(5), color: Colors.blue)),
          const SizedBox(
              height: 50,
              width: 50,
              child: Card(margin: EdgeInsets.all(5), color: Colors.blue)),
          const SizedBox(
              height: 50,
              width: 50,
              child: Card(margin: EdgeInsets.all(5), color: Colors.blue)),
          const SizedBox(
              height: 50,
              width: 50,
              child: Card(margin: EdgeInsets.all(5), color: Colors.blue)),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  )
```

Try to play around with the number of SizedBoxes and their sizes.

[image]

In your case, the error might be because there are no constraints for the ListView dimensions.